# How do I post a test Kinesis event from Postman to a local Lambda function running on serverless?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-kinesis

Sorry, wasn't sure how to make the question itself brief enough...

I can post data from Postman to my local Lambda function. The issue is that when running locally, I have use this line of code...

```
event = JSON.parse(event.body);
```

...so that I can do this...

```
event.Records.forEach(function(record)
{
   // do some stuff
}
```

But when I deploy the function to AWS, parsing event.body is unnecessary. In fact it throws an error.

I was assuming that there is something different about the JSON (or other aspects of the request) that I'm posting from Postman to my local app when compared to what Kinesis actually sends. But the JSON blob I'm posting locally was logged directly from Lambda on AWS to Cloudwatch.

I'm missing something.

TBH, this only matters because having to comment out that line as a step in the deployment process is annoying and error-prone.

Here's the JSON (names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "kinesis": {
                "kinesisSchemaVersion": "1.0",
                "partitionKey": "Thursday, 11 April 2019",
                "sequenceNumber": "49594660145138471912435706107712688932829223550684495922",
                "data": "some base 64 stuff",
                "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 1555045874.83
            },
            "eventSource": "aws:kinesis",
            "eventVersion": "1.0",
            "eventID": "shardId-000000000003:1234123412341234123412341234123412341234123412341234",
            "eventName": "aws:kinesis:record",
            "invokeIdentityArn": "arn:aws:iam::1234123412341234:role/lambda-kinesis-role",
            "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
            "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-west-2:1234123412341234:stream/front-end-requests"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: For my purposes for the moment, I've simply changed the line to:     
`if(event.body)
        event = JSON.parse(event.body);`

Comment: The `event` payload will have different structures depending on the source event, HTTP is different to Kinesis. If you want to test local use `invoke local` with your test payload instead of making HTTP requests.

Comment: @Alex is Kinesis not using HTTP to push data to Lambda?

Comment: The lambda event source is Kinesis not API Gateway which produces a different event payload. AWS underneath might use HTTP but thats not the reason the payloads are different.